# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4'

Tags: python, plotly

I am practicing Python and copied a code from a book (though I understand how it was made). I am encountering an error

Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 276398: character maps to 
File "C:\Users\Faizan\My Drive\Python\Practice_files\dice_visual.py", line 30, in 
offline.plot({'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}, filename='d6_d6.html')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 276398: character maps to

Here is the full code

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Layout
from plotly import offline

from die import Die

#Create two D6 dice
die_1 = Die()
die_2 = Die()

#Make some rolls, and store results in a list
results = []
for roll_num in range(1000):
    result = die_1.roll() + die_2.roll()
    results.append(result)

#Analyze the results
frequencies = []
max_result = die_1.num_sides + die_2.num_sides
for value in range(2, max_result+1):
    frequency  = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

#Visulaize the results
x_values = list(range(2, max_result+1))
data = \[Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)\]

x_axis_config = {'title': 'Result', 'dtick':1}
y_axis_config = {'title': 'Frequency of Result'}
my_layout = Layout(title='Result of rolling two D6 dice 1000 times', xaxis=x_axis_config, yaxis=y_axis_config)
offline.plot({'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}, filename='d6_d6.html')
```

I tried Google but couldn't find a solution

Comment: What's happening here: `data = \[Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)\]`?

Answer (score 0):

I am running into this problem with Python 3.11, but when I use Python 3.10 the problem went away. It might be a bug with Python or one of the packages we're using.

If possible, maybe try reverting to a different version.